# iframe-resizer IE11 issue on resizing and hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a couple of niggles re the iframe-resizer available from `https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer`.

If I resize the browser by using Restore Down, everything seems ok at first, if I resize the browser further down manually, the iframe resizes ok, depending on resolution a bit of extra padding appears.

However if you then try and resize up and increase the width of the browser window, the padding becomes much more evident and if you actually maximise the window the padding is ridiculous.

```
<iframe src="footer" style="width: 100%; border: 0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    iFrameResize({
        log: false,
        enablePublicMethods: true,
    });
</script>
```

Also is there a way to have local hyperlinks server within the iframe actually refresh the parent window?

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Following on, I have found a workaround, though it is not ideal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    iFrameResize({
        log: false,
        enablePublicMethods: true
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

This does address the padding when resizing up, but forces the page to reload on resize.

This code below addresses the extra padding issue on resizing up, without the need to reload:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('iframe').iFrameResize({
        log: false, autoResize: false,
        sizeWidth: true
    });
</script>
```

However, the resizing at certain sizes does not show all iframe content.

Unforunately the page reload is the only thing that truly addreses both issues so far, I'm hoping someone has a more elegant solution

Comment: I don't know the details of this particular strategy, but I use post message to communicate between host and child.

Comment: Was thinking a bit too complex about this, just adding `target = "_parent"` to the a tag resolved that specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the issue without reloading the page, the code for my solution is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('iframe').iFrameResize({
        log: false
    });

    function correctHeight() {
        var iFrameId = document.getElementById('iFrameResizer0');

        $(window).resize(function () {
            $(iFrameId).attr('style', 'width: 100%').attr('height', '0px');

            var contentHeight = iFrameId.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';

            $(iFrameId).attr('height', contentHeight).css('height', contentHeight);
        });
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
        correctHeight();
    }, false);
</script>
```